# How to identify the parallel edges in a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If we have a graph, how do we know what are the parallel edges?

[image]

Considering this graph which I found from a quick search in the web, what are the parallel edges?

In my view, I think paraellel edges are those that have same end-points?

So following that e4 and e5 have same end-points: (C, D).

Comment: Your understanding is correct.